# UIImageview Animation Starts using for-in loop and animation delays

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimageview, uianimation

I need to animate an UIimageview and when i start animation it happens after long time and i found that memory is leaked somewhere at the time of continuous animation for various image views. All I need to do is i have n number of UIviews in scroll view and each view have an custom button. when that button is selected an animation happens and if animation is in process if the user taps on button that animation will continue and it dont need to start again

here is my code

```
 for (int i=0; i<AlphabetArray.count; i++) {

    UIView *view=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 200)];
    view.backgroundColor=[UIColor grayColor];
    view.tag=i+1;
    [self.scrollView addSubview:view];
     UIImageView *image=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 50, 400, 400)];


    [image setImage:[[animationArray objectAtIndex:i]objectAtIndex:0]];
    image.tag=i+1;
    [view addSubview:image];

    UIButton *animatebutton=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 50, 336, 310)];
    animatebutton.tag=i+1;
    [animatebutton addTarget:self action:@selector(makeAnimation:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    //[animatebutton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"NewtDance_mov_0.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [view addSubview:animatebutton];
}

-(void)makeAnimation:(UIImageView *)sender {

UIView *tagView=(UIView *)[self.view viewWithTag:sender.tag];



for (UIImageView * imageview in [tagView subviews]) {

    NSLog(@"Yes %d",imageview.tag);


    if ([imageview isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {

        if ([imageview isAnimating]) {
            NSLog(@"Animation Happens");

        }

        else{
            imageview.animationDuration=3.0;

            imageview.animationImages=[animationArray objectAtIndex:sender.tag-1];
            imageview.animationRepeatCount=2;
            imageview.tag=sender.tag;
            [imageview startAnimating];
        }
    }

}



NSLog(@"OK");


}
```

With this code i can achieve what my requirement is about. But the animation starts very late because of for-in loop used

Comment: make sure your animation is perfect. then decrease animation duration. and check it out with break points also.

Comment: @Suresh i tried decrease animation duration still i faced same

Comment: Do you check with break points? where it stucks actually? is your animation is perfect?

Answer (score 5):

The best way to handle this. use `UIImageView`'s `animationImages` property.

1. Create `NSMutableArray` object using your Image's `UIImage` objects.
2. Set The Images array to the `UIImageView` `animationImages` property by
   `[imageView setAnimationImages:imagesArray]`
3. `[imageView startAnimating]` to Start Animations.
4. `[imageView stopAnimating]` to Stop Animations.
   Check the document's for more details.

For more details, [check this.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: The document hear. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: I didnt understand your answer

Comment: @damithH Now you only need to delete your second answer.