# Fast display UIImages in Objective-c

Tags: objective-c, performance, graphics, uiimage, cgimage

I'm streaming images to a client application. I want the images to display as fast as possible. I am able to receive images at 40-50 frames per second on the client, but can only draw them at a max of around 15 frames per second. I'd like to get at least 30FPS, but would also like to see if I can display them as fast as I receive them, up to 40FPS if possible. This is what I am currently doing, can it be drawn faster?

```
UIImage * image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
[self.mainImageView.layer setContents:(__bridge id)(image.CGImage)];
```

Comment: where are you calling this code ?

Comment: It's called when the image data is received off the socket connection.

Answer (score 0):

You can animate them GIF style as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15022449/uiimageview-animation-starts-using-for-in-loop-and-animation-delays)

and set the animation duration as follows:

```
self.mainImageView.animationDuration = NumberOfImages * 1.0f / 30
```

If that doesn't work, you might have to go into GL rendering.